# Options to run spatial analysis on Geomesa?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spatial, geotools, geomesa

Since Geomesa provides geospatial, temporal, and attribute-based querying capabilities for large datasets, I was wondering if there is any option to do spatial analysis such as overlap, intersect, buffer, spatial join.

I read from the manual (please correct me if I'm wrong) that it can be achieved from SparkSQL and PySpark. Is there any other option available?

Answer (score 0):

You can query for `intersects` and `overlaps` using [GeoServer](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) or [GeoTools](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/filter/query.html) directly with CQL filters, and you can transform results using functions like `buffer`.

Usually spatial analysis refers to more complex operations, such as `joins` or aggregates, and those usually require a distributed engine, since GeoMesa is used with large data sets. For that, GeoMesa supports [Spark](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/spark/index.html) for batch analysis, [Kafka Streams](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/kafka/streams.html) for streaming analysis, and integrates with [Apache Sedona](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/spark/sparksql.html#spark-sedona-integration) for more advanced operations.